# lolcommits with egit / egit commit hook

Tags: git, egit

Lolcomits is taking a webcam photo on each git commit, that's a real fun thing.

http://mroth.github.io/lolcommits/

But the git commit hook is not working in eclipse / egit.

How to trigger the commit hook in egit ?

Update 2014-05-11
There is an issue for this: https://github.com/mroth/lolcommits/issues/123
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=299315

Comment: Looks like a great project to do.